# can't connect to local mysql server through socket while running db using volume

Tags: docker, dockerfile

while running my db container it shows error

start-database.sh file:

```
!/bin/bash

# This script starts the database server.
echo "Creating user $user for databases loaded from $url"
```

Import database if provided via `docker run --env url="http:/ex.org/db.sql"`
echo "Adding data into MySQL"

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld &
sleep 5
curl $url -o import.sql
```

**Fixing some phpmysqladmin export problems**
`sed -ri.bak 's/-- Database: (.*?)/CREATE DATABASE \1;\nUSE \1;/g' import.sql`

Fixing some mysqldump export problems (when run without `--databases` switch)
This is not tested so far.

```
if grep -q "CREATE DATABASE" import.sql; then :; 
else 
  sed -ri.bak 's/-- MySQL dump/CREATE DATABASE `database_1`;\nUSE `database_1`;\n-- MySQL dump/g' import.sql; 
fi

mysql --default-character-set=utf8 < import.sql
rm import.sql
mysqladmin shutdown
echo "finished"
```

**Now the provided user credentials are added**

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld &
sleep 5
echo "Creating user"
echo "CREATE USER '$user' IDENTIFIED BY '$password'" | mysql --default-character-set=utf8
echo "REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM '$user'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" | mysql --default-character-set=utf8
echo "GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO '$user'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" | mysql --default-character-set=utf8
echo "finished"

if [ "$right" = "WRITE" ]; then 
echo "adding write access"
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '$user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" | mysql --default-character-set=utf8
fi
```

And we restart the server to go operational

```
mysqladmin shutdown

echo "Starting MySQL Server"
/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

ERROR:

`docker_admin@ubuntu:~$ **sudo docker run -v /home/docker_admin/datadb:/var/lib/mysql:rw --name mysqldb sqldb**`

Creating user root for databases loaded from file:/var/db/database.sql
Adding data into MySQL

> 151218 11:31:51 [Warning] Using unique option prefix
>   lower_case_table_name instead of lower_case_table_names is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name
>   instead. 151218 11:31:51 [Warning] Using unique option prefix
>   key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be
>   removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead. 151218
>   11:31:51 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
>   starting as process 5 ...   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average
>   Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100 1105M  100 1105M    0     0  49.7M      0  0:00:22  0:00:22
>   --:--:-- 22.1M ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) mysqladmin: connect
>   to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' Check that
>   mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
>   exists! finished 151218 11:32:30 [Warning] Using unique option prefix
>   lower_case_table_name instead of lower_case_table_names is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name
>   instead. 151218 11:32:30 [Warning] Using unique option prefix
>   key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be
>   removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead. 151218
>   11:32:30 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
>   starting as process 25 ... Creating user ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't
>   connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to
>   local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
>   ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) finished adding write access ERROR
>   2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) mysqladmin: connect to server at
>   'localhost' failed error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' Check that mysqld is running
>   and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists! Starting
>   MySQL Server 151218 11:32:35 [Warning] Using unique option prefix
>   lower_case_table_name instead of lower_case_table_names is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name
>   instead. 151218 11:32:35 [Warning] Using unique option prefix
>   key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be
>   removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead. 151218
>   11:32:35 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
>   starting as process 52 ...

Comment: i am having same issue, did u work it out?